# How to get Facebook Profile Name ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Facebook profile ID from graph, for example: https://www.facebook.com/**ravi.rajak1991**. I want the ID which comes after `facebook.com/`.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can´t get the ID by username anymore (ravi.rajak1991 would be the username), the possibility has been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API. The only way to get the ID of a user is to authorize that user. After authorization, you get an "App Scoped ID", you can use that one to identify returning users.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible anymore due the deprecation of the older Facebook API, for further details, see the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thanks @Mark Swedish